# Checking the closeness of probability distributions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose I have a Markov chain that satisfies all the conditions of ergodicity and has a stationary distribution pi. I want to find the time when the probability distribution of the markov chain is arbitrarily close to it's stationary distribution (pi), say within epsilon of the stationary measure.( The choice of distance function (eg L_1 norm or total variation distance etc) is completely up to you.).

Are there any analytical results in this area, or something that can be checked using simulations ? Any pointers will really be useful.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: Do you assume that you know stationary distribution, or only the fact that it exists and is limiting? Also, what do you mean by the probability distribution of a Markov Chain?

Comment: Yes, I know the stationary distribution exactly. By probability of the markov chain, I mean the probability distribution of the markov chain at any time t given some initial known distribution.

Comment: Well, [this book](http://probability.ca/MT/BOOK.pdf) has all about that - check Chapter 13 for example. However, they tackle a very general case, so maybe some clarification is good to have. In case of finite Markov chains, in that nutshell ergodicity means that $P$ (which has largest eigenvalue of $1$) starts acting on $\mu-\pi$ as a matrix whole largest eigenvalue is smaller than $1$, so that you get geometric convergence.

Comment: @ Ilya. Thanks so much for the reply and the reference.